# Store HTML contents in Rich Text field using RestLet

Tags: html, json, netsuite

I've a JSON containing some HTML contents from an External System. We have a Rich Text field for storing this HTML data. But I noticed, while storing I'm getting some HTML tags included in to the field as the HTML contents are coming as JSON string. So my question is how can I store the received JSON string data as a HTML back in Netsuite field. Is it possible ?

```
Jdata = dataIn.desc; //  getting something like : Guest(s) benifit's surcharges  <br><p>test benifit desc 25% discountpop &quot;test&quot;</p>
```

Thanks for your interest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try unescape or decodeuri, which are standard old js methods.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

If not just do a string replacement on the known char sets (" being the same as ")

Comment: I tried using escape previously but failed to produce the desired output in certain scenarios as the incoming data is mixed encoded. I end up using escape syntax. It worked for me. :)